# Alterar link com .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Tenho o seguinte link

```
 http://127.0.0.1/site/noticia/12(cod_da_noticia)
```

Queria saber como posso deixar o link assim

```
 http://127.0.0.1/site/noticia/12(cod_da_noticia)/queria colocar o titulo aqui
```

link no .htaccess

```
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^site/noticia/([^/]+)$ site/index.php?op=28&cod=$1 [L,QSA]
```

href

```
href="../noticia/<?php echo $registo['cod_noticia'];?>">
```

Comment: O link parte do <a href> e não do access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```js
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^site/noticia/([a-z0-9-]+)/(.*)/?$ /site/index.php?op=28&cod=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thx. O titulo aparece assim Graduacoes%20dos%20Judocas%20de%202016, como posso trocar %20 por -

Comment: Eu utilizo uma função em php para tratar os titulos removendo os caracteres especiais e espaços substituindo tudo por - e salvo no banco de dados junto com a tabela da noticia em um campo para a url, assim não preciso informar o id da notícia sempre que precisar buscá-la, simplesmente posso buscar pela url, fazendo isso a sua url ficará mais bonita e no código você pode usar da seguinte forma RewriteRule ^site/noticia/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /site/index.php?op=28&campo_da_url_na_tabela_noticia=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: $string = $registo['Titulo'];
$string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string);
meto a $string no href
feito
vai do engenho de cada um